# Python UDP binary data to job queue

Tags: python, binary, udp, job-queue

I'm planning on replacing a simple Perl script (that is too slow) with a Python one that processes incoming UDP datagrams that contain binary data, and for performance reasons I don't want to process the binary data immediately but pass it on to something like a job queue that will then process the data down the road via consumers to do uu-encoding and writing it to a database, file, etc.

My understanding is that most job queues, memcached, etc all want text data, not binary data.  Is there a simple way to pass binary data-gram data to a job queue or something else for processing later without the over head of converting it first?

Comment: why not remove the "replacing a simple Perl script" and just state "I want to write a python script". This isn't really a Perl question if it doesn't have any code...

Comment: Re "*My understanding is that most job queues, memcached, etc all want text data, not binary data*", Quite the opposite. Their interfaces may provide the means to encode text into bytes transparently, but they should all accept arbitrary bytes (i.e. binary data).

Comment: If not, just encode using base64.